# ObjectMapper - JSON string to Java Object not working

Tags: java, json, api, object-object-mapping

I have a requirement where I need to convert JSON response from an API and send it as XML to the end client.

I am able to successfully receive JSON (output pasted below) from the API but unable to convert it to Java Objects using ObjectMapper. I don't get any errors; but when I return "GetCardInfo" object it is null.

I have tried searching through google but unable to find why it is not working. It will be a big help if someone can help me understand what is the issue with my code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.Object;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.ws.Response;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import org.slf4j.ext.XLogger;
import org.slf4j.ext.XLoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.CardActivationResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.CardInfo;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.ErrorDetails;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.GetCardInfo;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.GetCardInfoReceiveJSONResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.GetCardInfoRequest;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.GetCardInfoResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.GetCardInfoSendJSONRequest;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.GetCardTransactionsReceiveJSONResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.GetCardTransactionsRequest;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.GetCardTransactionsResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.GetCardTransactionsSendJSONRequest;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.IVRKPNResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.IVRResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.IVRWrapperConstants;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.IVRWrapperResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.RequestContext;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.VerifyCardConvertResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.VerifyCardHolderReceiveJSONResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.VerifyCardHolderRequest;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.VerifyCardHolderResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.VerifyCardHolderSendJSONRequest;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.VerifyCardReceiveJSONResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.VerifyCardRequest;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.VerifyCardResponse;
import com.bhn.webservice.ivr.VerifyCardSendJSONRequest;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
  //XML mapper.
    ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
                   mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,
                        false);
                mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
GetCardInfo gci = mapper.readValue(JSONResponse.toString(),GetCardInfo.class);
```

Below is the output from JSONResponse.toString()

```
{
  "transactionId" : "RNQFBKGPZ4M18PLZJA4BDGC32W",
  "isCompleted" : true,
  "percentComplete" : "100",
  "card" : {
    "id" : "1000000000000098718",
    "bin" : "451129",
    "proxyCardNumber" : "603953510161946xxxx",
    "isActive" : false,
    "isRegistered" : false,
    "expirationDate" : "2017-06-30T23:59:59.000+0000",
    "serviceCode" : "121",
    "balances" : {
      "openingBalance" : "5000",
      "closingBalance" : "5000",
      "pendingBalance" : "5000",
      "currencyCode" : "USD"
    },
    "status" : "OPEN",
    "statusReason" : "NONE",
    "provisionType" : "PHYSICAL",
    "accountStatus" : "OPEN",
    "accountStatusReason" : "NONE",
    "product" : {
      "id" : "1000000000000000415",
      "name" : "EXM Visa Corp LAP",
      "isActive" : "true",
      "productIdentifier" : "07675023660",
      "bin" : "451129",
      "issuer" : "MetaBank"
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the class GetCardInfo

```
public class GetCardInfo {

    @XmlElement(name = "transactionId", required = true)
    public String transactionId;
    @XmlElement(name = "isCompleted", required = true)
    public Boolean isCompleted;
    @XmlElement(name = "percentComplete", required = true)
    public String percentComplete;

    @XmlElement(name = "card", required = true)
    public Card card; //Parent for remaining data

    public static class Card {
        @XmlElement(name = "id", required = true)
        public String id;
        @XmlElement(name = "bin", required = true)
        public String bin;
        @XmlElement(name = "proxyCardNumber", required = true)
        public String proxyCardNumber;
        @XmlElement(name = "isActive", required = true)
        public Boolean isActive;
        @XmlElement(name = "isRegistered", required = true)
        public Boolean isRegistered;
        @XmlElement(name = "expirationDate", required = true, type = String.class)
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
        @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
        public Date expirationDate;
        @XmlElement(name = "serviceCode", required = true)
        public String serviceCode;
        @XmlElement(name = "balances", required = true)
        public Balances balances; //Parent for balances data
        @XmlElement(name = "status", required = true)
        public String status;
        @XmlElement(name = "statusReason", required = true)
        public String statusReason;
        @XmlElement(name = "provisionType", required = true)
        public String provisionType;
        @XmlElement(name = "accountStatus", required = true)
        public String accountStatus;
        @XmlElement(name = "accountStatusReason", required = true)
        public String accountStatusReason;
        @XmlElement(name = "product", required = true)
        public Product product; 

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Card [id=" + id + ", bin=" + bin + ", "
                    + "proxyCardNumber=" + proxyCardNumber + ", isActive=" + isActive
                    + ", isRegistered=" + isRegistered + ", expirationDate=" + expirationDate
                    + ", serviceCode=" + serviceCode + ", balances=" + balances
                    + ", status=" + status + ", statusReason=" + statusReason
                    + ", provisionType=" + provisionType + ", accountStatus=" + accountStatus
                    + ", accountStatusReason=" + accountStatusReason + ", product=" + product + "]";
        }
    }

    public static class Balances {
        @XmlElement(name = "openingBalance", required = true)
        public String openingBalance;
        @XmlElement(name = "closingBalance", required = true)
        public String closingBalance;
        @XmlElement(name = "pendingBalance", required = true)
        public String pendingBalance;
        @XmlElement(name = "currencyCode", required = true)
        public String currencyCode;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Balance [openingBalance=" + openingBalance + ", closingBalance=" + closingBalance + ", "
                    + "pendingBalance=" + pendingBalance + ", currencyCode=" + currencyCode + "]";
        }
    }

    public static class Product {
        @XmlElement(name = "id", required = true)
        public String id;
        @XmlElement(name = "name", required = true)
        public String name;
        @XmlElement(name = "isActive", required = true)
        public String isActive;
        @XmlElement(name = "productIdentifier", required = true)
        public String productIdentifier;
        @XmlElement(name = "bin", required = true)
        public String bin;
        @XmlElement(name = "issuer", required = true)
        public String issuer;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Card [id=" + id + ", bin=" + bin + ", "
                    + "name=" + name + ", isActive=" + isActive
                    + ", productIdentifier=" + productIdentifier + ", issuer=" + issuer + "]";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GetCardInfo [transactionId=" + transactionId
                + ", isCompleted=" + isCompleted
                + ", percentComplete=" + percentComplete
                + ", card=" + card + "]";
    }   

}
```

EDIT:
I put a catch block for IOException and found that I am getting below IOException. This would mean that there is something wrong with my JSON String.

Added my POM.xml below. Also added imports above for the Java file that has the ObjectMapper.

catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(
                    "IOException - ",
                    e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

```
IOException -  com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <organization>
        <name>xxx</name>
        <url></url>
    </organization>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.bhn.poms</groupId>
        <artifactId>component-parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <artifactId>ivr-wrapper-service</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.bhn.webservice</groupId>
    <version>1.2.26-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>IVR Wrapper Service Implementation</name>
    <description>This project defines the java implementation for this service.</description>

    <properties>
        <bhn-entity-management-version>2.32</bhn-entity-management-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bhn.webservice</groupId>
            <artifactId>entity-management-service</artifactId>
            <version>${bhn-entity-management-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bhn.webservice</groupId>
            <artifactId>ivr-wrapper-domain-model</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bhn.webservice</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-service-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@xxx.com:7999/custom/ivrwrapper.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@xxx.com:7999/custom/ivrwrapper.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

</project>
```

EDIT: based on @minus comment I have converted my JSON string to an XML string as below

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(JSONResponse.toString());
                xml = XML.toString(json);
                logger.info("GetCardInfo XML Response for KPN API: {} ", xml);
```

The log shows that it got converted to XML successfully.

```
<percentComplete>100</percentComplete><transactionId>FL2YTNR86KARMVYWWVK3410F4W</transactionId><card><product><productIdentifier>07675023660</productIdentifier><bin>451129</bin><name>EXM Visa Corp LAP</name><id>1000000000000000415</id><isActive>true</isActive><issuer>MetaBank</issuer></product><serviceCode>121</serviceCode><bin>451129</bin><isActive>false</isActive><proxyCardNumber>6039535101619469382</proxyCardNumber><accountStatusReason>NONE</accountStatusReason><accountStatus>OPEN</accountStatus><balances><pendingBalance>5000</pendingBalance><closingBalance>5000</closingBalance><openingBalance>5000</openingBalance><currencyCode>USD</currencyCode></balances><statusReason>NONE</statusReason><provisionType>PHYSICAL</provisionType><isRegistered>false</isRegistered><id>1000000000000098718</id><expirationDate>2017-06-30T23:59:59.000+0000</expirationDate><status>OPEN</status></card><isCompleted>true</isCompleted>
```

Next I am using below code to deserialize the XML String back to the Java object. But the deserialize is not working.

```
   GetCardInfo gci = mapper.readValue(xml, GetCardInfo.class);
                    logger.info("Test12 ", gci.toString());
```

Now I don't get any error but Deserialization did not work. The fields in GCI object are null.

Comment: Code that compiles and runs, along with a pom.xml and the imports would help.

Comment: Thanks. I have added pom.xml and import. I am still working to put a code that compiles and runs. This application has multiple files so need to build a new fresh application to demonstrate this error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not big at Jackson but you are trying to deserialize a json document with an XML mapper.

Jackson is telling you exactly that, you can't start an xml with '{'.

You should use a JsonMapper to deserialize Json and then an XMLMapper to serialize it.

I don't know if it is possible annotating the same class for both.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Based on your comment I converted my JSON String to an XML string as below:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @minus for his input.
I was able to figure out answer

all I needed was to add the classname to my XML string as below

String input = "" + xml + "";
After that I was able to deserialize successfully.